# How to make particles move in spirals?

Tags: javascript, animation, image-processing, html5-canvas, pixel

I've been trying to make a pixel rain for base64 images with javascript's context.getImageData(). It already creates a lot of particles moving from left to right with changing speeds depending on the brightness of the image and a color based on their position.

I want to make the particles move in a spiral from the canvas borders to the center and then return to the borders once again.

The code snippet can't be runned because of myImage.src, it has to be a base64 image, but these are to long for presenting here (you can use this page to create the source preferably with a small image, https://onlinepngtools.com/convert-png-to-base64).

```js
const myImage = new Image();
myImage.src = 'base64 image'

myImage.addEventListener('load', function() {
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
canvas.width = 600;
canvas.height = 714;

ctx.drawImage(myImage, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
const pixels = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
// ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

let particlesArray = [];
const ParticlesAmount = 7000;

let mappedImage = [];

for (let y = 0; y < canvas.height; y++) {
    let row = [];
    for (let x = 0; x < canvas.width; x++) {
        const red = pixels.data[(y * 4 *pixels.width) + (x *4)];
        const green = pixels.data[(y * 4 *pixels.width) + (x *4 + 1)];
        const blue = pixels.data[(y * 4 *pixels.width) + (x *4 + 2)];
        const alpha = pixels.data[(y * 4 *pixels.width) + (x *4 + 3)];
        
        const brightness = calculateRelativeBrightness(red, green, blue);
        const cell = [
            cellBrightness = brightness,
            cellColor = 'rgb(' + red + ', ' + green + ', ' + blue + ', ' + alpha + ')'
        ]
        row.push(cell);
    }
    mappedImage.push(row);
}

// For the human's eye perception.
function calculateRelativeBrightness(red, green, blue) {
    return Math.sqrt(
        (red * red) * 0.299 +
        (green* green) * 0.587 +
        (blue * blue) * 0.114
    );
}

class Particle {
    constructor() {
        this.y = Math.random() * canvas.height;
        this.x = 0;
        this.speed = 0;
        this.velocity = Math.random() * 5;
        this.size = Math.random() * 1.5 + 1;
        this.position1 = Math.floor(this.y);
        this.position2 = Math.floor(this.x);
    }

    update() {
        this.position1 = Math.floor(this.y);
        this.position2 = Math.floor(this.x);

        let movement = this.velocity * 5;

        if (
            this.position1 >= 0 &&
            this.position1 < mappedImage.length &&
            this.position2 >= 0 &&
            this.position2 < mappedImage[0].length
        ) {
            this.speed = mappedImage[this.position1][this.position2][0];
            let movement = (2.5 - this.speed) + this.velocity;
        
        this.x += this.velocity;
        if (this.x >= canvas.width) {
            this.x = 0;
            this.y = Math.random() * canvas.width;
        }
        }
    }

    draw() {
        ctx.beginPath();
        if (
            this.position1 >= 0 &&
            this.position1 < mappedImage.length &&
            this.position2 >= 0 &&
            this.position2 < mappedImage[0].length
        ) {
            ctx.fillStyle = mappedImage[this.position1][this.position2];
        } else {ctx.fillStyle = 'white'}
        ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.size, 0, Math.PI * 2);
        ctx.fill();
    }
}

function init() {
    for (let i=0; i < ParticlesAmount; i++) {
        particlesArray.push(new Particle());
    }
}

init();

function animate() {
    ctx.globalAlpha = 0.05;
    ctx.fillStyle = 'rgb(0, 0, 0)';
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    for (let i=0; i < particlesArray.length; i++) {
        particlesArray[i].update();
        particlesArray[i].draw();
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}
animate();
})
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    background-color: #222;
}

#canvas {
    border: 2px solid #f5f5f5;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    width: 660px;
    height: 714px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Pixel flow</title>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please create a [mre].

Comment: Where does `myImage` come from? And does the code work if you just draw a rectangle instead of an image?

Comment: myImage is created through the src property, since ctx.getImageData() only reads base64 images, I didn't write the full source. You can use https://onlinepngtools.com/convert-png-to-base64 to create the base64 source.

It doesn't work with rectangles, but it could work if you get the rectangles color manually, since getImageData wouldn't work (unless you somehow get an image of the canvas).

Comment: @MrJosephCharles Is the problem solved now or still needs an Answer? Also is there a visual example (_eg:_ Youtube) of a "nearest" to the animation that you want to create?